# Trying to replace NaNs with the [0:2] Index of the same Column

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I extracted some gambling data from online and exported to Excel. Now trying to clean up a few columns.

The spread for each team was pulled into the same column. I am able to extract each one except the whole numbers.

Code:

```
df['Away Spread'] = df['Open'].str.extract(pat= '([-+A-Z].[^-/+].[0-9]?)').fillna(df['Open'].str[0:2])
```

Output:

[image]

Desired Output:

[image]

Best Output:

[image]

If the best output can't be accomplished in one line, **please don't tell me**. I should be able to convert 'Away Spread' to float and then make 'Home Spread' the opposite. I just can't help feeling I missed something in my regex pattern.

Thanks to all who take a look!

Comment: @RookiePython you should include an example of that and the desired result in your Question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
df['Away Spread'] = df['Open'].str.extract(r'([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)', expand=False).fillna(df['Open'].str[0:2])
```

*Notes*:

- `.extract(r'([-+]?\d*\.?\d+)', expand=False)` - extracts the first positive or negative float/integer number (`expand=False` will make sure the result is a series, not a df)
- `.fillna(df['Open'].str[0:2])` will fill the values where no match occurred with the first two chars of the values from the `Open` column.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HUvFho/1) (I added `^` to only match at the start of the lines , see also `m` flag).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this directly in Excel by finding the second instance of `+` or `-`

First half

```
=LEFT(A1,MAX(FIND("+",A1),FIND("-",A1))-1)
```

Second half

```
=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-LEN(B1))
```

[image: excel]

Comment: I was really only thinking of doing it with Python so I can do it automatically each week, but this works as well!! Thanks!